# Why I get error ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I installed the `AWS toolkit` for java and connected it to my project in buildpath, I tried to upload file to `S3`.

```
File fileOfImages = new File("/sdcard/Save Image Tutorial");
AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());        
s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest("rosh-haayin-images", "images",fileOfImages));
```

but I get following error :

```
ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider
```

Could someone explain why this exception occurs?

Answer (score 2):

It means you are missing aws-java-sdk-1.10.X.jar in your project build path.

```
$ jar tvf /home/xxx/aws-java-sdk/1.10.52/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.10.52.jar |grep AWSCredentialsProvider
  3485 Thu Feb 11 22:22:34 IST 2016 com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProviderChain.class
   233 Thu Feb 11 22:22:34 IST 2016 com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider.class
   806 Thu Feb 11 22:22:34 IST 2016 com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.class
```

verify that your project refers(Java Build Path) to the jar.

Comment: thank , but i refers to all the jars included in aws toolkit sdk for java.i do it in the buildpath, what else i have to do?